# Tic-Tac-Toe-x for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04, snap

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS have automatically update Tic-Tac-Toe game from version 1.3 to version 1.6 throught latest/stable snap repository but unfortunately it doesn't work properly (it does not respond properly to mouse inputs). Are latest/stable snap repository untested?